# Checking if cherrypy is active

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a process that starts up cherrypy runs a task and then needs to check if it is still running or has completed it's task.  I am running python 2.6.7

```
 while True:
      if t1.isAlive():
           cherrypy.engine.start()
      else:
           cherrypy.engine.stop()
           print "server down"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. It depends what you really want. Do you want to check if a process is still alive and kicking, or do you need some feed-back information?

Or do you just have to check for an output (file/log/db)? Give us some more information. Some code-examples would clarify your problem

I guess you could take a look at the [PIDFile](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/refman/process/plugins/pidfile.html) plugin. With this plugin you could even do a Multiprocess or a check independent of which process started a cherrypy-instance.

Just after the start you initialize the pidfile-plugin and check anywhere outside if the file exists. Only caveat, it may block on zombie-processes or if the pidfile doesn't get erased.

Comment: At the moment I have:


while True:
 if t1.isAlive():
  cherrypy.engine.start()
 else:
  cherrypy.engine.stop()
  print "server down"

where I have cherrypy.engine.start() I want it to check if it is running already, if so just continue, if not to start it.

Comment: Don't answer with comments, just update your initial question. So your cherrypy and your threads are running in the same process?

Comment: Sorry, Cherrypy is in the calling thread, the main code is a child thread.